# Serialization of PyObjects in Cpython

Tags: python, serialization, cpython, python-c-api

I am trying to write a PyObject in a file(in bytes) and then access it via other instance of Python interpretor. Although my main goal is to somehow have some PyObjects in a shared memory so that other python vm instance can access these objects in this shared memory. But as far as I know, shared memory (atleast in linux) also works like files, for example writing in a file descriptor and reading from a file descriptor. Therefore, I would need to convert the PyObject into bytes, store it in some file and ask the other python interpretor to read this file.

Going along this direction, I have written the following function which accepts a python integer object, stores it in a file and then reads it again and returns it.

```
PyObject* func(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    // Writing the Object to a file                                   //1
    const char* const path = "file.bin";                              //2
    FILE* file = fopen(path,"wb");                                    //3
    fwrite( args, sizeof(PyLongObject) , 1 , file );                  //4
    fclose( file );                                                   //5

    //Reading the Object from the file
    file = fopen(path,"rb");                                          //6
    PyObject* contents = NULL;                                        //7
    contents = PyMem_Malloc( sizeof(PyLongObject) );                  //8  
    fread( contents, sizeof(PyLongObject) , 1 , file );               //9
    fclose( file );                                                   //10
    
    //Forcing the REFCOUNT to 1
    Py_SET_REFCNT(contents,1);                                        //11

    return contents;                                                  //12
}
```

So if I import this function from the module, and give an input as an integer it works. Meaning that it writes that integer pyobject into the file, closes the file, and then the file is opened again, to transfer its content, to another pyobject variable and then returns it. So if I pass in 1 as an argument, 1 is returned as an pyobject.

But after thinking about it for some hours I have multiple doubts.

1. At line #4, if I understand correclty, I am also hardcoding all the pointers enclosed within this object, which will be rendered useless, when I will try to open it from a different python vm, because all the addresses will be different.
2. At line #8, I use PyMem_Malloc here, so therefore I shoud use free somewhere along the line ? Or will the python vm will call the free once this "content" object refcount reaches 0 ?
3. At line #11, I force the refcount of my new object to be 1, because the old object (args) refcount is also copied here and could be more than 1. Is this the correct thing to do ?
4. What will happen if my initial object (args) reaches to a refcount of 0? Since I have copied all the pointers from "args" to "contents", will deleting args, also delete the original objects which "args" was pointing to and hence making the pointers inside "contents" useless. This I tried, as follow

```
>>> from some_module import func
>>> a = 999999
>>> b = func(a)
>>> del(a)
>>> b
999999
```

The "content" variable still works for some reason. Why does this work or is my understanding wrong somewhere in between ?

5. Last and not Least, what is the actual correct way to do the above thing. That is to sterilize python objects into files and then read them again via a file.

Comment: why not use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov as far as I know, pickle only works with objects whose definition is present in the present module or the definition of the class from which the object is created is available ( I think it has to do with __getstate__ and __setstate__.) In my case I do not or the code does not have access to the object class definition, so I would like to do it manually. I know many details will be involved by doing it manually, but I think this is a good starting point.